# Xamarin Forms Switch's Toggled event not being triggered when using custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `Xamarin.Forms` app and I have created a custom `Switch` as below:

```
public class ExtSwitch : Switch
{
   public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchOnColorProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchOnColor),
                                  typeof(Color), typeof(ExtSwitch), Color.Default);

   public Color SwitchOnColor
   {
      get { return (Color)GetValue(SwitchOnColorProperty); }
      set { SetValue(SwitchOnColorProperty, value); }
   }

   // More codes here //
}
```

In My `XAML` I used it like:

```
<local:ExtSwitch Grid.Column = "2"
       IsToggled="{Binding IsToggled}" 
       Toggled="Handle_Toggled"
       SwitchThumbColor="White" 
       SwitchOnColor="Red" 
       SwitchOffColor="Gray"
       HorizontalOptions="End" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

In My C# code I have a `Handle_Toggled` method that handles what happened when the Swich is toggled. But somehow the `Toggled` event is not being triggered when used inside my custom switch but works perfectly when used in a normal switch.

Can someone point to me what am I missing here or what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Custom renderer in iOS:

```
class ExtSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
   {
       base.OnElementChanged(e);

       if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null) return;

       ExtSwitch s = Element as ExtSwitch;

       UISwitch sw = new UISwitch();
       sw.ThumbTintColor = s.SwitchThumbColor.ToUIColor();
       sw.OnTintColor = s.SwitchOnColor.ToUIColor();

       SetNativeControl(sw);
    }
}
```

Using the above code:

[image]

Using the code suggested below:

[image]

Custom renderer in Android:

```
public class ExtSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        public ExtSwitchRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }
        ExtSwitch s;

       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Switch> e)
      {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null)
            return;

        s = Element as ExtSwitch;
        if (this.Control != null)
        {
            if (this.Control.Checked)
            {
                this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(s.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(s.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
            }
            this.Control.CheckedChange += this.OnCheckedChange;
        }
        Control.Toggle();
    }

    void OnCheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Control.Checked)
        {
            this.Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(s.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
            this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(s.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(s.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
            this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(s.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code from your custom renderer on Android/iOS?

Comment: @sme please see the edits above

Comment: did you ever find out why the event wasnt being triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the native control, instead just update the current Control, like this:

```
this.Control.ThumbTintColor = s.SwitchThumbColor.ToUIColor();
this.Control.OnTintColor = s.SwitchOnColor.ToUIColor();
```

And theres no need to call `SetNativeControl`

Comment: This would definitely trigger the `Toggled` event. But this would also alter the appearance of the switch buttons. Please see the above image

Comment: It might be due to setting the ThumbTintColor. Try to comment out that line and see what happens `//this.Control.ThumbTintColor = s.SwitchThumbColor.ToUIColor();`

Comment: This works great in iOS. I forgot to put the Android code. Would you mind looking at another edits above for the android side? Thanks

Comment: The Android side also doesn't trigger Toggled when clicked?

Comment: A simple way to do it would be to go to your `MyProject.Droid/Resources/values/style.xml` file, and add the following to your theme: `<item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>`, but of course this would mean you can only set the color once for your whole app. Plus it'll update the accent color of other controls

Comment: Otherwise, perhaps check this out https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/249767/#Comment_249767

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 7):

on IOs renderer

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);



        if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null) return;

        CustomSwitch s = Element as CustomSwitch;



        //this.Control.ThumbTintColor = s.SwitchThumbColor.ToUIColor();
        this.Control.OnTintColor = s.SwitchOnColor.ToUIColor();

    }
```

and Android renderer in OnCheckedChange

```
private void OnCheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
   {
        if (this.Control.Checked)
        {
            this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        }

        Element.IsToggled = Control.Checked;


    }
```

Comment: Without this line, toggling the switch has no effect. `Element.IsToggled = Control.Checked;`

Answer (score 0):

`SetColorFilter` is deprecated in the meantime. With package Xamarin.AndroidX.Core you can use the renderer like this:

```
public class ColoredSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    private readonly Android.Graphics.Color _defaultColor = ((Color)Application.Current.Resources["Default"]).ToAndroid();
    private readonly Android.Graphics.Color _activeColor = ((Color)Application.Current.Resources["Active"]).ToAndroid();
    private readonly Android.Graphics.Color _inactiveColor = ((Color)Application.Current.Resources["Inactive"]).ToAndroid();

    public ColoredSwitchRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        SetThumbColor();
        UpdateTrackColors();
        Control.CheckedChange += OnCheckedChange;
    }

    private void SetThumbColor()
    {
        var filter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.CreateBlendModeColorFilterCompat(_defaultColor, BlendModeCompat.SrcAtop);
        Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(filter);
    }

    private void OnCheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateTrackColors();
        Element.IsToggled = Control.Checked;
    }

    private void UpdateTrackColors()
    {
        if (Control.Checked)
        {
            var filter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.CreateBlendModeColorFilterCompat(_activeColor, BlendModeCompat.Src);
            Control.TrackDrawable?.SetColorFilter(filter);
        }
        else
        {
            var filter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.CreateBlendModeColorFilterCompat(_inactiveColor, BlendModeCompat.Src);
            Control.TrackDrawable?.SetColorFilter(filter);
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Control.CheckedChange -= OnCheckedChange;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

and for the sake of completeness the iOS renderer:

```
public class ColoredSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("Active", out var activeColor);
            Control.OnTintColor = ((Color)activeColor).ToUIColor();

            Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("Default", out var defaultColor);
            Control.ThumbTintColor = ((Color)defaultColor).ToUIColor();

            Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("Inactive", out var inactiveColor);
            Control.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].BackgroundColor = ((Color)inactiveColor).ToUIColor();
        }
    }
}
```